Detailed Explanation of PKI Certificate User Authorization of HTTP Requests
I need to enable NodeJS access to Windows Certificate Store.
Saving the certificate to a file is not an option.
I am working on extending NodeJS to access the Windows certificate store for user authentication and authorization supporting of OATH 1.0,2.0 and perhaps SAML.
I have successfully built a project and have the C code searching the store or invoking the GUI to choose a certificate, then accessing it and getting the properties in the same format as I see in certificate manager.
I also get the cert in PEM format to a string, that matches the file when I export.
The PEM formatted string includes the public key, NOT the private key.
When using a smart card and logging into a web site using OATH, I am prompted for my card’s PIN.
Implying I am encrypting or decrypting something with the private key.
I can only find top level diagrams of the process… any detail or code involves Basic Authorization  user/password or Bearer tokens…
I need to understand what functions NodeJS needs exposed from the store, beyond:
Find a cert
Return it’s properties ( in strings)
Get the Cert in PEM format with public key (in a string)
…what’s next?????
To support OATH and SAML using client certificates
Do I need to decrypt something sent back from the server?
Session cookie???

[link] (https://www.yubico.com/resources/glossary/what-is-certificate-based-authentication/) has a top level explanation that requires sending the certificate and an encrypted nonce to the server. Where does the nonce go in the HTTP(s) request???
